# IPSec Tunnel not coming up: Issue with ACL?

Tags: cisco, ipsec, tunnel

I'm trying to bring up a IPsec tunnel between router and a bridge. I can see the Ipsec tunnel configurations are up and running but I think I have made a mistake in the ACL and hence the encr and decr counters are still 0.

Can someone guide me on this?

```
    SGLAB-C881K9#sh ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override

Gateway of last resort is not set

      10.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 2 subnets
C        10.50.50.10 is directly connected, Loopback0
R        10.110.248.10 [120/4] via 192.168.2.10, 00:00:06, FastEthernet4
      192.168.2.0/24 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        192.168.2.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet4
L        192.168.2.1/32 is directly connected, FastEthernet4
SGLAB-C881K9#
```

Diagram:
[image]

Desktop(ETH0)-->(FE3 SVI)Router(FE4 WAN)-->(ETH0)Master Bridge(RF0)-->(RF0)Remote Bridge(ETH0)-->>Client.

Router Model: Cisco 881K9

Tunnel is between Loopback created on Router and RF0 Interface on Remote Bridge.

Configuration:
https://pastebin.com/hfSQGpMu

```
Router configuration:
SGLAB-C881K9#
SGLAB-C881K9#
SGLAB-C881K9#sh run
Building configuration...

Current configuration : 2043 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 11:09:09 UTC Fri Nov 16 2018
version 15.3
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname SGLAB-C881K9
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
aqm-register-fnf
!
enable secret 5 $1$bEYB$z5Jz9F7gED/aMzosGxRe01
enable password <Masked>
!
no aaa new-model
!
!
!
!
!
!


!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!
!
!
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
license udi pid C881-K9 sn FGL2101208A
!
!
username ssn privilege 15 secret 5 $1$2N/d$gqvkb2e6IZLUCEE5oVhG20
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 1
 encr aes
 authentication pre-share
 lifetime 3600
crypto isakmp key 4B0u7WnF6vFGSdy2QARJ0U09SaK1CvCW address 10.110.249.1
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set bridge11f7d8 esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
 mode tunnel
!
!
!
crypto map TST local-address Loopback0
crypto map TST 10 ipsec-isakmp
 set peer 10.110.249.1
 set transform-set bridge11f7d8
 match address bridge11f7d8_ACL
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface Loopback0
 ip address 10.50.50.10 255.255.255.255
!
interface FastEthernet0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet2
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface FastEthernet3
 no ip address
!
interface FastEthernet4
 ip address 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex full
 speed auto
 crypto map TST
!
interface Vlan1
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
!
router rip
 network 10.0.0.0
 network 192.168.2.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
!
!
ip access-list extended bridge11f7d8_ACL
 permit icmp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.110.193.0 0.0.0.3
 permit tcp 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 10.110.193.0 0.0.0.3 eq 20000
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
mgcp behavior rsip-range tgcp-only
mgcp behavior comedia-role none
mgcp behavior comedia-check-media-src disable
mgcp behavior comedia-sdp-force disable
!
mgcp profile default
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
 no modem enable
line aux 0
line vty 0 4
 password <Masked>
 login
 transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
!
end

SGLAB-C881K9# sh crypto ipsec sa

interface: FastEthernet4
    Crypto map tag: TST, local addr 10.50.50.10

   protected vrf: (none)
   local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0/6/0)
   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.110.193.0/255.255.255.252/6/20000)
   current_peer 10.110.249.1 port 500
     PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,}
    #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
    #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
    #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
    #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
    #pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
    #send errors 0, #recv errors 0

     local crypto endpt.: 10.50.50.10, remote crypto endpt.: 10.110.249.1
     plaintext mtu 1500, path mtu 1500, ip mtu 1500, ip mtu idb FastEthernet4
     current outbound spi: 0x0(0)
     PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none

     inbound esp sas:

     inbound ah sas:

     inbound pcp sas:

     outbound esp sas:

     outbound ah sas:

     outbound pcp sas:

   protected vrf: (none)
   local  ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (192.168.1.0/255.255.255.0/1/0)
   remote ident (addr/mask/prot/port): (10.110.193.0/255.255.255.252/1/0)
   current_peer 10.110.249.1 port 500
     PERMIT, flags={origin_is_acl,}
    #pkts encaps: 0, #pkts encrypt: 0, #pkts digest: 0
    #pkts decaps: 0, #pkts decrypt: 0, #pkts verify: 0
    #pkts compressed: 0, #pkts decompressed: 0
    #pkts not compressed: 0, #pkts compr. failed: 0
    #pkts not decompressed: 0, #pkts decompress failed: 0
    #send errors 12, #recv errors 0

     local crypto endpt.: 10.50.50.10, remote crypto endpt.: 10.110.249.1
     plaintext mtu 1500, path mtu 1500, ip mtu 1500, ip mtu idb FastEthernet4
     current outbound spi: 0x0(0)
     PFS (Y/N): N, DH group: none

     inbound esp sas:

     inbound ah sas:

     inbound pcp sas:

     outbound esp sas:

     outbound ah sas:

     outbound pcp sas:
SGLAB-C881K9#
```

Comment: What is the bridge configuration?  What traffic(addresses)  are you trying to pass in the tunnel?

Comment: The bridge is a proprietary device. I will update the configuration soon. In the mean time, Could you please check my ACL w.r.t to ipsec end points?

I have also pasted the crypto ipsec sa output in the pastebin link.

Does the ACL rules align with my peer endpoints?  local crypto endpt.: 10.50.50.10, remote crypto endpt.: 10.110.249.1

Comment: You need to edit your question to include the network device models and configurations. Simply past the configurations into your question using the Preformatted-text option (`{}`).

Comment: Sure,Ron. I have updated the query as advised

Comment: We can't tell if the ACL is correct unless you tell us what traffic you're trying to pass through the tunnel.

Comment: Please include the routing table for your router (`show ip route`).

Comment: Also, I do not see where you have applied the ACL, nor are you advertising the `192.168.1.0/24` network in RIP, and you should be using the `no auto-summary` option for RIP along with with version 2 of RIP.

Comment: Where is the tunnel interface in the configuration?

Comment: Appreciate you quick response Ron. I have updated a small diagram,Route info. I have just also advertised 192.168.1.0/24 into the rip. But it is still itsn't working

Comment: What is the purpose of the ACL, and why is it not applied anywhere? Where is the tunnel interface, and why do you want a tunnel? The router is not receiving the `10.110.193.0/24` and `10.110.249.0/24` networks from RIP, so it has no idea how to send anything to those networks, including the `10.110.249.1` endpoint. I simply do not see the need for a tunnel or the crypto if all you want is for the two PCs to communicate.

Comment: This looks like a IKE phase 1 issue. Can you do a show crypto isakmp on the router and also paste the config for the bridge device? the settings will need to match and the ACL on the bridge will need to be the inverse of the one you have on your router.

Comment: @RonMaupin  The ACL is in the cryptomap, which is applied to Fe4

Comment: @Maverick You don't have a route to 10.110.193.0, so traffic will never go into the tunnel

Comment: OK. I'm still not sure why you need the crypto, but your router will definitely need to have a route to `10.110.193.0/24` in order for the router to be able to send traffic to that network, otherwise the router will drop the traffic as an unknown destination.

Comment: Okay,I need to fix the routing issue first.Then I will start working on the IPsec configuration. Thanks for all the pointers,I will ensure ping towards 10.110.249.0/24 and 10.110.193.0/24 as a first step on troubleshooting

Comment: @RonMaupin I have fixed the routing issue and also corrected the ACL.It is working with  esp3des. Now I need to demo AES 128 + SHA1 and AES256 + SHA256  working on the configuration. But it doesn't seems to be working. Does anyone have a working baseline configuration for AES128/AES256 ipsec conf?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.